# web technology from chrome inspector. is the page written in rails, node.js, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

As the title states, how can I find out if a webpage was written in a certain framework or language for example in node.js or php, rails etc?

Comment: It is difficult to check that but here is the extension which mostly corrects you can install on chrome which can help you in this. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Currently I use two tools :

- Wappalyzer [extensions](https://www.wappalyzer.com/download)
- BuiltWith [extensions](https://builtwith.com/toolbar) (available on more browsers)

Wappalyzer is a bit more clearer when it comes to interface, BuiltWith comes with a bit more details. I cross the results for better understanding.

Works for most sites but sometimes fails (as it can't tell me for Stackoverflow for instance).